# Using: Airflow to Clone repo to GCS bucket and commit repo from GCS Bucket

Tags: python, git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I am having a problem cloning the GitHub repo to the GCS bucket using Apache Airflow. Upon researching and trying POC on this I am still unable to figure it out.

Use Case:

- Once the repo has been cloned, Airflow DAG will access the repo and implement the logic accordingly. Finally, the updated changes will be committed and pushed back to the GitHub Repo in a feature branch.

I probably have to make a custom GitToGSCOperator or GitOperator for this, but does anyone know a better way to do it?

Comment: Did you try the GithubOperator?

https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/github/modules/githuboperator
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-github/1.0.1/operators/index.html

Comment: No, I haven't. I will give it a shot though. Thanks @FedericodosReis